# Build openSSL with bitcode

Tags: ios, openssl

I'm trying to build openSSL 1.1.0 with bitcode.

At the makefile I defined

```
CC= $(CROSS_COMPILE)clang -fembed-bitcode
```

But then I got the error

```
ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Without the bitcode, it works well.

How can I build it with bitcode support?

Comment: Be careful of using bitcode. Its an intermediate representation that can be rewritten before delivery. The rewritten routines may not perform as well as expected, and may not arrive at the expected result. Personally, I'd much rather have Andy Polyakov's hand tuned implementations then something a code generator provides.

Comment: Maybe you are right and I'll just leave it without bitcode. With hope it won't be necessary someday..

Comment: Also see this issue report in the OpenSSL GitHub tracker: [Issue 2601, Build for iOS32 (armv7) only runs with no-asm (1.1.0d)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2601).

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I'll try to keep an eye on that issue

Comment: Yep, tested it and the app couldn't start. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, end up using this script to do it - 
https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone